# Create a list object in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create a list of point patterns ppp.object {spatstat} in a loop.
My dataset looks like this:

```
> names(OT1);head(OT1);dim(OT1)
[1] "EID"       "latitude"  "longitude" "month"     "year"      "CPUE"      "TSUM"     
[8] "fTSUM"    
                EID latitude longitude month year CPUE TSUM fTSUM
1   167-1-1996-1135 67.70000 -61.81667     9 1996    0    0     F
2  167-10-1996-1135 67.71667 -59.18333     9 1996    0    0     F
3 167-100-1996-1135 67.86667 -59.43333    10 1996    0    0     F
4 167-101-1996-1135 67.95000 -59.58333    10 1996    0    0     F
5 167-102-1996-1135 68.10000 -59.76667    10 1996    0    0     F
6 167-103-1996-1135 67.81667 -59.38333    10 1996    0    0     F
[1] 2707    8
```

What I would like to do is to select data for each of my month and create a ppp.object.

```
> sort(unique(OT1$month))
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

The following loop works and I can see each of my figures:

```
for(i in sort(unique(OT1$month))){ 
  a<-OT1[OT1$month==i,]
  b<-ppp(a$longitude,a$latitude,marks=a$fTSUM,window=newW)
  plot(b,main=i)
}
```

I would like to create a list of all my ppp.object that I can access individually, I've tried adding a list() in the loop command but without any success... Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please do *not* crosspost between r-help and here. Bad karma.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Why not? Is everyone who frequents the [R] tag here also a follower of R-help? It seems like two completely distinct communities to me.

Comment: @eykanal I'd be willing to bet that nearly every R tag regular on SO at least lurks on R-help.

Comment: Yes, but not everyone who is *looking* for assistance with R will search both here and R-help. I'm not sure I agree with the suggested restriction.

Comment: @eykanal For me, it's more simply about politeness. Asking for help here or on R-help is essentially asking for busy folks to take time out and help you for free. If the consensus among those communities is that cross-posting is discourage (and it is, given by their FAQs) then it's just polite to respect that.

Comment: @joran - sorry if I offended anyone here, I didn't realized that cross posting was seen this way in the community (never heard about it until now).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like a good fit for `lapply`:

```
pppList <- lapply(sort(unique(OT1$month)), function(i) {
  a<-OT1[OT1$month==i,]
  ppp(a$longitude,a$latitude,marks=a$fTSUM,window=newW)
})
```

...But just to explain how to fix you for-loop:

You need to have a list to assign to. And creating one of the correct length is always a good idea for performance:

```
x <- sort(unique(OT1$month))
pppList <- vector('list', length(x))
for(i in x) { 
  a<-OT1[OT1$month==i,]
  b<-ppp(a$longitude,a$latitude,marks=a$fTSUM,window=newW)
  pppList[[i]] <- b
  plot(b,main=i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tommy! I was struggling on how to code the list function! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Would the following work for you?

```
library(plyr)
dlply(OT1, .(month), function(a) ppp(a$longitude,a$latitude,marks=a$fTSUM))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an empty list of the correct length first, and then assign each `ppp` object to a slot in that list in turn.

```
ind <- sort(unique(OT1$month))
b <- vector("list", length(ind))
for(i in 1:length(ind)){ 
    a <- OT1[OT1$month == ind[i],]
    b[[i]] <- ppp(a$longitude,a$latitude,marks=a$fTSUM,window=newW)
    plot(b[[i]],main=ind[i])
}
```